# Return value from on an onclick radio button

Tags: javascript

Trying to return a value from a function based on radio input however I keep getting either a null or

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')".

```js
function myFunction() {
  var radioTest = document.querySelector('input[name="inputtest"]:checked').value;
  return radioTest;
}

var test = myFunction();
console.log(test);
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="test123" name="inputtest" value="testing 123" onclick( "myFunction();") />
```

Comment: It's because `input[name="inputtest"]:checked` doesn't exist because your radio button isn't checked. `input[name="inputtest"]` does exist, so you can check its `checked` status within the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the page is loaded, there is no checked input.
To make it work for both page load and input checked, you can use [Optional Chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for the assertion.

Also, the syntax is invalid. Instead of

```html
onclick( "myFunction();")
```

use

```html
onclick="myFunction()"
```

Here is the full code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var radioTest = document.querySelector('input[name="inputtest"]:checked')?.value;
  console.log(radioTest);
  return radioTest;
}

var test = myFunction();
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="test123" name="inputtest" value="testing 123" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

A note: I'd recommend to use `onchange` in case you have more than one radio button in your form.

Comment: Thank you.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: You are welcome :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.

1. The way you are attaching the click event.
2. You are calling myFunction() on load. So it is throwing an exception because raiobutton is not checked.

Use the below code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var radioTest = document.querySelector('input[name="inputtest"]:checked').value;
  return radioTest;
}

function handleClick()
{
  let radioValue = myFunction();
  console.log(radioValue);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="test123" name="inputtest" value="testing 123" onclick = "handleClick()" />
```

Comment: Thank you.  As with the previous suggestion, it appears it has something to do with the page/radio button checked.